# Mysql query vertical "\G" not working

Tags: mysql

I have a question about query data with vertical format, I tried it with \g or \G .

I referenced "4.5.1.6.2 Displaying Query Results Vertically" at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tips.html

But it not working and show error syntax at "\G"

My query :

```
select * from mytable \G . Always wrong.
```

From that, I just want to build final query like this:

```
Select "A","B","C","D" as "ColumnName" \G
```

Expect:

```
ColumnName    
A    
B    
C    
D
```

I tried with UNION or UNION ALL. but with several thousand record, it's slow performance.

And mysql version is : Server version- 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

@ Bernd Buffen

I show my query:

```
Select C.* from 

(

  (  Select * from (Select "Value1" as newcolumn UNION ALL Select "Value2" as newcolumn UNION ALL ...<200.000 UNION ALL>)   ) A

left join  

(SELECT key,column1,column2,colum3 FROM supplier ) B

on A.newcolumn = B.key 

) C
```

And handle query to database, I debug time from Begin to End, it spend from 1.30 to 2 minutes. It is not good.

Comment: it works only in the original mysql client

Comment: Are you mean it just run into code behind.

Answer (score 5):

The \G and \g features are just features of the command line client (as mentioned in the comments.)

MySQL when used from a programming API (even another program, like phpMyAdmin or a MySQL GUI) does not support \g or \G.  It doesn't even "display" data.  Display is done by the GUI program, instead.

However, even if you ran this query:

```
SELECT 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' AS "ColumnName"\G
```

In the command line client, it would actually produce:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         A: A
         B: B
         C: C
ColumnName: D
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is because you've selected 4 columns in that query, and only named the last one 'ColumnName'.

If you want to see the rows of the table you would run:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name\G
```

And then it would list each column, then a `:`, then the value.

Nevertheless, this would only work with the command line client.

If you're wanting to retrieve a key, value from the database via a programming API, the problem is definitely a bit trickier.  A UNION is going to end up being what you want, e.g.:

```
SELECT 'column_name_1' AS key, GROUP_CONCAT(column_name_1) AS value
FROM table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'column_name_2' AS key, GROUP_CONCAT(column_name_2) AS value
FROM table_name
```

But yes, it's not likely to be efficient.

This isn't really the way databases are meant to be used - they're meant to be used as a table of data.  I'd suggest you change the data to this format after you've retrieved it from MySQL.  You might do this in an array, or similar.

Comment: thank you. About statement \G, I understood it only working in command line. About your last statement sql. I tried it, but I cannot use union all, it ok, but when I loop it than 200.000 records ,it lost more time, and website not response with error 500

Comment: Right.  If you really need to do this, I would suggest you pull down * from the table (in row format) and then transpose the data in a buffer (after it has left MySQL.)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one more Sample.**

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TMPV;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TMPV` (
  `newcolumn` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`newcolumn`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `TMPV` VALUES ('Value1'),('Value2'),('Value3'),('Value4'),('Value5'),('Value6');


SELECT A.*, s.`key`, s.`column1`, s.`column2`, s.`column2` 
FROM `TMPV` A
LEFT JOIN supplier s
  ON A.newcolumn = s.key;
```

Comment: but it only working on command line  to display. I need it in API.thank you.

Comment: @thanhlong - i gave change my answer, but i dont know why you want to do this

Comment: I agree with you about union all statement. But if I have 200.000 records, Union All will slow performance when them union every items(more than 2-3 minutes, website will display error 500, not response). Because I want to left join those 200.000 records from 200.000 parameters with another tables exist in database, yes->left join and get all 200.000 record with null and not null include of them.At the current, just 200.000 records, but in the  future, maybe it more than 200.000.

Comment: @thanhlong - can you me post the "slow" query from you with a short sample what you expected and if possible a explain of the SELECT

Comment: of course, I post my query string. It is in php API, and I can debug it with the time it spend.Thanks.

Comment: @thanhlong - in have change my answer. be sure that is a index supplier.key

Comment: Thank for your support. I thought this solution if we have only 1 user. But if it was a system with multiple user, data of this user will be deleted by others user (it is impossible), I cannot create for everyone with 1 table and maintainance it.

Comment: @thanhlong - ok, but you can create this short table as TEMPORARY TABLE, direct before you use it. So every user can have his own tmp table with the same name. MySQL create it per connection and its only visible in this connection

Comment: Your solution very perfect. I tried it many time and it worked success into Mysql Server, but It not success with Mysqli or PHP PDO, it not working with multiple statement in one query.